# System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Caller_Info_Attributes.PropertyChangedEventArgs'

Tags: c#

I have code from Albahari but can`t realise it.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Caller_Info_Attributes
{

        public interface INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        }
        public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler
        (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
        public class PropertyChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public extern  PropertyChangedEventArgs(string propertyName);
            public virtual string PropertyName { get; }
        }

        public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
            void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            string customerName;
            public string CustomerName
            {
                get { return customerName; }
                set
                {
                    if (value == customerName) return;
                    customerName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                    // The compiler converts the above line to:
                    // RaisePropertyChanged ("CustomerName");
                }
            }

    }

    class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.CustomerName = "abra";
            foo.PropertyChanged += Foo_PropertyChanged;
            foo.CustomerName = "dada";
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Foo_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        static void propertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.PropertyName is "dada")
                Console.WriteLine("what is changed really?");
        }
    }
}
```

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
>   'Caller_Info_Attributes.PropertyChangedEventArgs' from assembly
>   'Caller_Info_Attributes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' because the method '.ctor' has no implementation
>   (no RVA).'

I have exception at RaisePropertyChanged(); 
And public extern  PropertyChangedEventArgs(string propertyName) not work without **extern** modifier?
How can I rewrite it in this way to work with events and CallerMemberName]?

I rewrite to

```
public class PropertyChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{

    public PropertyChangedEventArgs(string propertyName) { PropertyName = propertyName; }
    public string PropertyName { get; }

}
```

and get

```
System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'
```

O, It works normally. :)

Comment: Using `extern` makes no sense, you must delete it.

Comment: Thanks. I already deleted it and add body